# Is there a way I can get appium to start within the code?

Tags: appium

I am trying to launch the appium server within the code I am writing using Java.
I tried the following command and it doesn't work:

```
appium = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/appium");
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work". What's the error?

Comment: There is no error, at least I can't see one. Just that the appium server doesn't start. It's like the command is passed but it's not executed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to start Appium on OS X you should include 'open' and add a '.app' at the end.

For example:

`appium = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Applications/Appium.app");`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I'm using Ruby.
The issue was not that the server was not starting, the server was running but when the scripts were executed it was failing like if the server was not running.
What worked for me was to start Appium as a separate thread.
with ruby it was like this:

```
Thread.new{run_command('avm use 1.3.4 --no-reset &',1,5,false)}
```

I guess there should bu something similar that can be done in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The below steps worked fine for me

- Follow the steps for installing the Node and npm here. (http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows)
- Command prompt : `npm install -g appium@1.3.7` #for latest
- Make sure to include the path where you have installed the Appium in your System Environment variable (mine is `C:UsersXXXAppDataRoamingnpmnode_modulesappiu`)
- Add the below code in BeforeTest to start appium server programmatically

  ```
  CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");
  command.addArgument("/c");
  command.addArgument("appium");
  DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
  DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
  executor.setExitValue(1);
  executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StartandEndServer {
    public static void startServer() throws ExecuteException, IOException, InterruptedException{
        CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");  
        command.addArgument("/c"); 
        command.addArgument("C:/Progra~2/nodejs/node.exe");  
        command.addArgument("C:/Progra~2/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js");  
        command.addArgument("--address", false);  
        command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");  
        command.addArgument("--port", false);  
        command.addArgument("4723");  
        //command.addArgument("--no-reset");  
        command.addArgument("--full-reset", false);

        DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();  
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();  
        executor.setExitValue(1);  
        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);  

        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```